# Angular app keeps saying message does not exist

Tags: django, angular, chat

I'm building a chat app with Angular and Django using the get stream tutorial. https://getstream.io/blog/realtime-chat-django-angular/

However, I'm trying to run the app to create the chat view but it keeps saying 'messages' does not exist at the point marked 'this point' in the code.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { MessageResponse, Channel } from 'stream-chat';

import { StreamService } from '../stream.service';
import { StateService } from '../state.service';

declare const feather: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chat',
  templateUrl: './chat.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chat.component.scss'],
})

export class ChatComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    public streamService: StreamService,
    private stateService: StateService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  messages: MessageResponse[] = [];
  message = '';
  channel!: Channel;

  async sendMessage() {
    if (this.message) {
      try {
        await this.channel.sendMessage({
          text: this.message,
        });
        this.message = '';
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
  }

  getClasses(userId: string): { outgoing: boolean; incoming: boolean } {
    const userIdMatches = userId === this.streamService.currentUser.messages.id;   (this point)
    return {
      outgoing: userIdMatches,
      incoming: !userIdMatches,
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: The error is from `this.streamService`. You'd need to show this service here.

Comment: In the tutorial you linked `ChatComponent` has a `async ngOnInit` method. You're missing that.

Comment: I added the async ngOnInit method. I just removed it to show less code.

Comment: @MichaelD What do you mean? Is there meant to be a different file for that?